# Multiple Sharepoint Visual studio workflows in One Project - Best Practice

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

We have a requirement where we have to develop 5 Visual Studio Workflows as part of the project.  Based on the Best Practice for SharePoint Workflows (as discussed in the below Link), it is advised that whenever a code update is done to the workflow, create a new version of the workflow assembly(including change the WSP Name and Solution ID) rather than overwriting the older versions as existing instances may fail.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc514224.aspx#MOSS2007DevWorkflowSolutions_SavingWorkflowState

If my project had a single workflow we would not have any issue. However since we have 5 workflows we are not sure whether we should have all the workflows in one visual studio project or should we have individual project  for each workflow.  Kindly Advise.

Below are our analysis of the Pro’s and Con’s of each method…..

All Workflows in a Single Project with each workflow having its on feature

Pro’s

1.One single VS Project consisting of all the workflows and One DLL for each version.

Con’s

1.For Any change in one workflow, we will be creating  new features for the rest of the 4 workflows as the solution and the wsp name will be different. Hence the newer  version  of all the workflows will appear on the Manage Features page.
Each Workflow in a Single Project. :- Create a Project for each workflow.

Pro’s

1.Any change to one workflow will not create additional feature appearing  for the other workflows.
Cons

1.Multiple Projects and hence  Multiple wsp’s will have to be deployed. Multiple DLL’s will deployed to GAC.